# Many choices in one model's field?

Tags: django, django-models

I have

```
`   CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('A', 'B', 'C')
    )`
```

and I would let field:

```
myChoice = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
```

have many values from CATEGORY_CHOICES (1-3).

I am just starting use Django so an example will be nice :)

Comment: For clarification: You want to be able to select multiple values with your CharField? So you can select A AND C at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you horribly opposed to using a [ManyToMany relationship](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield)?  This relationship type is designed for exactly what you're trying to do.  It would create another table in the database instead of being a list in Python, but it would get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use

```
myChoice = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField()
```